# Using "All" twice in a row in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Would "We're all all talk." or "We're all, all talk." be correct? Ignore how bad it sounds. Which one would be correct?

Comment: 'Ignore how bad it sounds. Which one would be correct?' is a flouting of Orwell's sixth rule, considered by some to be the most important rule in English. Grammaticality is not the only (and sometimes not the prime) requirement for acceptability.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is predicated on the assumption that there is an indisputably acceptable answer among the two suggested. I'd use "We're _all_ all talk." if that were the required quote.

Comment: I dislike all all-terrain vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

The occurrence of two identical words in sequence is no justification for a comma. The first "all" means "all of us" and the second "all talk." Your sentence isn't elegant, but I don't think too many native speakers would have to read it twice to get the sense.

Comment: To me as a non-native, the comma would clarify the meaning. But I'm afraid you're right and using a comma would be an error.

Comment: A sentence in bad or clumsy style can still be grammatically correct.

Comment: I totally disagree. 'All all' appears, to me, to be a typo unless something is done to clarify it.

Comment: Yet, miraculosly, you managed to understand the sentence without such aid.

Comment: 'A sentence in bad or clumsy style can still be grammatically correct.' Like 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.' Grammatical, but (outside language analysis) incorrect on other grounds. OP asks 'Which one would be correct?'

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but the version with the comma expresses the thought more clearly.

There is some provision for using commas for readability.

> Use commas sparingly, only when breaks are needed for readability and to avoid confusion or misinterpretation.
>   [- apsstylemanual.org](http://www.apsstylemanual.org/oldmanual/mechanics/commas.htm)

I think your example is one that can lead to confusion without the comma. You're distinguishing "we're all talk" (talking about the team or group as a unit) from saying that each member of the group is "all talk".

However, if the comma comes across as a little jarring there, consider using a different punctuation mark such as an ellipse:

- We're all ... all talk.

Comment: The  comma would make it unintelligible except perhaps to native speakers of Japanese, where I understand it's common to separate subject and predicate with a comma.

Comment: Up-voted. I fully agree with @Lawrence. 'All all' looks like a typo to me and it needs something - anything - to make it readable. 'We are all, everyone of us, all talk' would be better.

Comment: @KarlG I don’t know much Japanese. I answered this as an English speaker. The version without the comma is more likely to be dismissed as a typo, where *all* was inadvertently duplicated.

Comment: The OP said to ignore "how bad it sounds," which is what I'm doing. Does the grammar of the sentence require a comma? Not in the least. Would some other punctuation be helpful, like an m-dash or ellipsis? Perhaps, but that wasn't the question. Inserting a comma just makes a bad situation worse.

Comment: @KarlG I didn’t say it was ungrammatical; I prefer the version with the comma because it expresses the thought more clearly.

Comment: @KarlG I've edited to make this explicit in my answer.